Transformations of the parabola
I think I have a very simple question regarding the transformation of the parabola.  (This is for Algebra $2$ in an US high school). For example lets say I have the quadratic
$$ f(x)=x^2-3x-3. $$
In vertex form, this is
$$ f\left(x\right)=\left(x-\frac{3}{2}\right)^{2}-\frac{21}{4} $$
Suppose I want to create another function that is a vertical stretch of $f(x)$ by $3$ to create another function $g(x)$.
What I am confused is, when I apply this vertical stretch are the roots maintained or is the vertex location maintained.
Normally I would think that
$$g(x)=3f(x)$$
which would maintain the roots but the vertex would now move.
However, if I start from the vertex form, would the constant get multiplied by $3$ or not? For example, would $g(x)$ be
$$g(x)= 3\left(x-\frac{3}{2}\right)^{2}-\frac{21}{4}$$
This would stretch $f(x)$ by $3$ and maintain the vertex location but the roots would change. They both seem right and I am not sure which is the desired transformation. Almost everywhere I look (including ChatGPT) the constant also gets the multiplied as well. What I don't understand is why?
When discussing transformations of the function $x^2$ in class, they say it is vertically stretched by a factor $2$ then shifted down $2$ units. Here final equation is
$$f(x)=2x^{2}-2$$
The constant does not get the $2$ multiplied to. Is that because the original function had $0$ as the constant?
I had one other question, regarding transformations. Again, let's say I have the function $c(x)$
$$c\left(x\right)=\left(2x+7\right)^{2}-3$$
I would like to apply a horizontal stretch of $3$ and horizontal shift of $3$ units to the left.
Does this mean that I have to do this:
$$ x \rightarrow 3(x+3) $$
Which results in
$$c\left(x\right)=\left(2\cdot3(x+3)+7)\right)^{2}-3$$
or
$$ x \rightarrow 3x+3 $$
These are different. When applying the horizontal stretch, how do you take care of the horizontal shift?
Thanks again for any help.

The x-intercepts will stay the same because they are located on the line $y=0$. The transformation you are doing is $y_{new}=3\times y_{old}$ and so the new equation is $g(x)=3\times[(x-\frac{3}{2})^2-\frac{21}{4}]=3(x-\frac{3}{2})^2-\frac{63}{4}$

Oh I see...points are on the y=0 and 0*3 = 0, so the x intercepts won't change. All because they are on the line y=0 where as everything else is on y=non-zero number they will get moved.

Another way of thinking of this is that the graph is unchanged, but the scaling units on the $~y~$ axis are multiplied by $~3.~$
For example, the point $~(0,1)~$ becomes the point $~(0,3).$
Note that with this approach, the aspect ratio between the $~x~$ and $~y~$ axes has been changed from $~1::1~$ to $~1::3.$
If desired, to restore the $~1::1~$ aspect ratio, you have to then stretch the graph (and the $~y~$ axis) vertically, by a factor of $~3.$

When you are transforming functions, the order of operations matters.
Even for arithmetic on numbers, the order of operations matters. If you multiply $9$ by $2$ and then subtract $2$ you get $16$, but if you start again with $9$, subtract $2$, and then multiply by $2$ you get $14$.
In your example in class, you vertically stretched by a factor $2$, then shifted down $2$ units. If you start with $x^2$, that means the vertical stretch multiplies by $2$ to give you $2x^2$, and then the shift subtracts $2$ to give you $2x^2 - 2$.
If the example were instead to shift down $2$ units then vertically stretch by the factor $2$, you would have had to do the subtraction first to get $x^2 - 2$, then multiplication to get $2x^2 - 4$.
Vertical stretching is usually done relative to the $x$ axis, which makes it simple because you just multiply the value of the function by  a constant.
Unless someone explicitly says they're doing something different, I assume that's what they mean by a "vertical stretch."
In the case of the function
$$f\left(x\right)=\left(x-\frac{3}{2}\right)^{2}-\frac{21}{4} \tag1$$
a vertical stretch of $f(x)$ by the factor $3$ means you multiply by $3$ and get the function $g(x) = 3f(x)$. That means all of $f(x)$ gets multiplied by $3$. You don't "reach inside" the definition of $f(x)$, pull out a part of the definition, multiply only that part by $3$, and then put it back.
What you do is you take the entire right-hand side of Equation $(1)$ and multiply by $3$, like this:
$$ 3f(x) = 3 \left(\left(x-\frac{3}{2}\right)^{2}-\frac{21}{4}\right). $$
That's a perfectly good and correct definition of $3f(x)$ right there.
But if you want to write the definition of $3f(x)$ differently -- for example to put it into a proper vertex form -- just follow the normal rules of arithmetic to figure out what to do. Multiplication distributes over addition, so that tells you that
$$ 3f(x) = 3 \left(x-\frac{3}{2}\right)^{2} - 3 \left(\frac{21}{4}\right)
= 3 \left(x-\frac{3}{2}\right)^{2} - \frac{63}{4}. $$
See, there are no super-secret rules of multiplying functions by constants. It's just the same old arithmetic you studied years ago.

Again let say I have the function $c(x)$
$$c\left(x\right)=\left(2x+7\right)^{2}-3$$
I would like to apply a horizontal stretch of $3$ and horizontal shift of $3$ units to the left.

It depends on what you mean by "stretch and shift". Do you want to stretch and then shift, or do you want to stretch in addition to a shift that you already did?
If you want to stretch horizontally by $3$ and then shift left by $3$, the correct transformation is:
$$  \text{Replace $x$ by $\frac{x + 3}{3}$}. $$
You may notice that neither of your transformations matches this.
That's because the horizontal stretching by $3$ is accomplished by dividing by $3$, not multiplying.
You can see this in what happens to the roots: for $c(x) = 0$ the roots are
$$ -\frac72 \pm \frac{\sqrt3}{2}, $$
which implies that the horizontal distance between the roots of $c(x) = 0$ is $\sqrt3$.
So when you stretch by $3$ horizontally, you want to end up with roots $3\sqrt3$ units apart.
And indeed the roots of
$$ \left(2\left(\frac{x + 3}{3}\right)+7\right)^{2}-3 = 0 $$
are
$$ -\frac{27}{2} \pm \frac{3\sqrt3}{2}, $$
so they are $3\sqrt3$ units apart, exactly as required.
Also, the $x$-coordinate of the vertex went from $-\dfrac72$ to $-\dfrac{21}{2}$ due to the horizontal stretch by factor $3$,
and then to $-\dfrac{27}{2}$ due to shifting left $3$ units.
You might want to practice stretching some simpler functions horizontally until you get the knack of it, which is basically remembering that whatever you want to do to the $x$-coordinates of the graph, you have to "undo" all of it to the value of $x$ wherever it appears in the formula of the function.
In this case you wanted to multiply the $x$-coordinate by $3$, then subtract $3$, so to "undo" that inside the formula you have to add $3$ to $x$ (first undo the last thing you did) and then divide the result by $3$.

(+1) Nice answer. I recently wrote about the types of student problems I designed to help integrate the algebraic and geometric halves involved.

Thank you. That clears much of my doubt.

Consider graphs of
$$ y=ax^2+bx+c$$
and
$$ m y=ax^2+bx+c$$
where $m$ is a real number , which is the the y-axis stretch factor.

For a symmetrical parabola ( axes red) roots can be found when solving with $b=0$ from the quadratic equation
$$ ax^2+c=0 ; x= \pm\sqrt{-c/a} $$
The roots do not change due to $y$ stretch, so also when the parabola is unsymmetrical (green) wrt y-axis when $ b\ne 0,  ~ (x_1,x_2)= (-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac})/(2a)$ do not change.
However the min/max value at $ x= -b/2a $ does change due to $m$ stretch:
$$y_{min,max}= c-b^2/4a \to m(
 c-b^2/4a) $$
In integral calculus when a curve with given roots is found by integration the arbitrary constant pushes the graph up or down leaving its roots unchanged.

Suppose the original function is $y = x^2 - 2$. The vertex of this function is at $(0,-2)$. If the $y$-axis stretch factor is $2$, is the vertex of the "stretched" function at $(0,-4)$ or at $(0,-1)$? Try putting $x=0$ into the equation $2y=x^2-2$ and solve for $y$. Does the result make sense to you?

In vertical or y- stretch /dilatation the parabola graphs set is given by [ set variable m],  $ y=m (x^2-2).$ To find their roots we set $y=0$. For  parabolas with stretch factors $(m=2, m= \frac12) $ vertex is at $(0,-4)$ and  $(0,-1)$ respectively but the roots remain same, i.e, at  the same x-axis location....    The same happens if you consider another x-shifted  parabola case to start with e.g., $ y=m * x (x-2\sqrt{2})$.   For the second question in your comment to find roots of $ 2y= x^2-2$ we put $y=0$ but not $x=0$.

That is a complete non-response to my comment. Looking closer at this answer, I am seeing even more mistakes: the graph of $y=ax^2+bx+c=0$ is not a parabola but consists of zero, one, or two points depending on the number of roots of $ax^2+bx+c=0$. That is, when you write $y=ax^2+bx+c=0$ you are saying (among other things) that $y=0$ and therefore only points on the $x$-axis can be on the graph. As for the graph of $2y=x^2-2$, the vertex (I never said anything about roots!) is at $(0,-1)$. See https://www.desmos.com/calculator/3khihexoup.

I know it's not protocol but I would like to thank everyone for adding their comments. I understand these translations with much more clarity. I feel that I don't have to memorize weird rules anymore to get the questions right.

OK, did my answer help you?
